# Does cancelling a coroutine cancel the write to a file?

Tags: kotlin, file, coroutine, cancellation, kotlin-companion

```kotlin
suspend fun copy(oldFile: File, newFile: File): Boolean{
     return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            var inputStream: InputStream? = null
            var outputStream: OutputStream? = null
            try {
                val fileReader = ByteArray(4096)
                inputStream = oldFile.inputStream()
                outputStream = FileOutputStream(newFile)
                while (true) {
                    val read: Int = inputStream.read(fileReader)
                    if (read == -1) {
                        break
                    }
                    outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read)
                }
                outputStream.flush()
                true
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "${e.message}")
                false
            } finally {
                inputStream?.close()
                outputStream?.close()
            }
        }

}
```

In the above code, if I cancel the job that is running the function, does the copying gets cancelled or do I have to manually check for state of the job inside while loop using ensureActive()?

Comment: No, copying will not be cancelled.

Comment: will there be any suspension points?

Comment: There are no calls to any of the suspend functions here, so all code will run to the end or until some exception occurs. The "Finally" block will work anyway.

Comment: So I am confused on why Dispatchers.IO is preferred if there aren't any suspend functions being called... Could you please explain why Dispatchers.IO are used for copying of file?

Comment: Its purpose is to run blocking code off the UI thread.

Comment: So if we are using coroutines, can you think of any scenario where managing multiple threads are better than just dispatching it to Dispatchers.Default or Dispatchers.IO?

Comment: Yes, for example, threads are preferable for heavy calculations. Coroutines are designed for tasks that wait for something most of the time, like some API responses.

Comment: Since Dispatchers.Default or Dispatcher.IO will switch to another thread anyway, is it necessary to create a new thread ourself?

Comment: Why? Unless you need to copy tons of files asynchronously, while some other I/O operations must be performed in parallel.